# How to script fsvs when using an assembla svn repository?

Tags: svn

Is it possible to use fsvs with a svn repository established on www.assembla.com, and can fsvs commands then be scripted?

Assembla offers small free subversion repositories that are easy to set up and use with actual svn commands, I've been using it for a short while and it works OK with straight svn, but when you get to the point where you want svn to capture user-group-permissions of things, you must either come up with your own methods, find other partially developed methods out there such as asvn, or try using more developed methods such as fsvs; hence the desire to use fsvs on assembla. The trouble is I can't figure out how to set it up such that I can script fsvs commands with out having the commands ask for a password.

I know you can use ssh keys and svn+ssh with some repositories to avoid having to enter passwords, but is this possible using assembla svn repositories?

Answer (score 0):

There's both good news and bad news...

The good news is that it is possible to use fsvs with assembla. Just create a svn repository on assembla. For the most part you can use fsvs commands just like you would svn commands (for example fsvs checkout URL; see fsvs help and http://www.tigris.org for more).

The bad news is that you have to enter your assembla username and password every time you execute an fsvs command. As of today (4/11/2014) according to assembla support, assembla does not provide a method of registering ssh.pub keys for svn+ssh authentication; only for git. This makes scripting interactions with the repository very difficult, both for fsvs and for svn for that matter. It is possible to do it with svn, but you leave your username and password exposed as you must script your commands like so: "svn add file --username user --password pwd" Yuck!  That said I wouldn't recommend it... If you want to use fsvs, you probably should set up your own repository. There is a pretty good explanation for how to do this here: http://techblog.tgharold.com/2007/05/fsvs-for-sysadmins.shtml

Also, just a few comments about the pros and cons of fsvs, subversion, and git: each of these seems to have their own deficiencies. svn does not natively handle user-group-permission info, but it is good for locking files (because binaries don't need merging).  fsvs keeps track of user-group-permissions, but does not have locking features and does not support the same global arguments that svn does (such as --username). As far as I know, git does not provide the best locking scheme either, but it seems to work well for all code based projects and seems to have better free repository support available. At least from assembla (and probably github too???)...